# How can I get rid of unnecessary paths being printed in Visual studio Code Terminal?

Tags: python, anaconda, visual-studio-code

**Every time I run my python script in VScode I get the following lines printed in the terminal:**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

E:\My Laptop\Coding\Python\Study files\Projects>C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate

(base) E:\My Laptop\Coding\Python\Study files\Projects>conda activate base

(base) E:\My Laptop\Coding\Python\Study files\Projects>C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe "e:/My Laptop/Coding/Python/Study files/Projects/100_Clean.py"
```

**than program executes normally. When execution ends, I get this line:**

```
(base) E:\My Laptop\Coding\Python\Study files\Projects>
```

**Why are these lines being printed? How can i turn them off in VSCode settings?**

Comment: the Python extension uses this to activate the environment and to execute the python file independent of what the current directory is

Comment: Thanks! is there any way to disable it? there are some terminal commands that fix it. so I guess in theory it should be possible to set up the VScode terminal in such a way that it first executes the command that fixes it and then the actual code. But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: `it first executes the command that fixes it` was wondering about this as well and found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most convenient way is to edit your user `settings.json` like so

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "prompt $G"],
```

Now my integrated terminal looks like so

```
>C:/Users/guido/miniconda3/Scripts/activate
(base) >conda activate condavenv
(condavenv) >
```

---

Alternatively, you can look for Code Runner extension in the marketplace - which has the option to do exactly what you want: *only the output of the code is printed and nothing else*.

Comment: or $G$S for "> " so that the command isn't touching the prompt

Comment: The normal  ">" touches the prompt though (e.g. C:\Users\guido\cpython>....)

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there is no way to hide the paths because the VS Code Integrated Terminal is basically using your OS/system's underlying terminal. And running Python scripts on a terminal usually requires you to specify a path.

One workaround is to use "prompt" command in the same terminal window before running your code.
Like this:

```
prompt $$
```

The other workaround is to use debug console as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

`(base) E:\My Laptop\Coding\Python\Study files\Projects>` isn't from your program, it is the area to type your command in the command prompt (in VS Code).

Comment: yes, I know that it's not because of my program. It's probably some VS code setting and I want to turn it off. So that it doesn't print these paths every time I run the script. My problem is not so much with the last printed line as it is with the lines that are printed before the code executes.

Answer (score 0):

One of the above working solution seems to have been deprecated; you can adjust your vscode settings for`"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows":`

example:

```
 "Command Prompt": {
       "path": ["C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"],
       "args": ["/K", "prompt $G$S "],  }
```